# PHP MySQL Proper Method to use Update

Tags: php

Question: what do I do to update the first column result with the value,instead of the last?

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(
mysql_query("SELECT canadd FROM myusers WHERE IP='{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']'");
$tq=$row['canadd'];
if ($tq==3)
die('you cannot add anymore users!');
++$tq;
mysql_query("UPDATE myusers SET canadd='{$tq}' WHERE IP='{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}' ");
```

that updates the results like this(what happens when I execute the code twice):

before:

```
canadd | IP   | ETC.
1      | myip | etc.
```

after:

```
canadd | IP   | ETC.
1      | myip | etc.
2      | myip | etc.
```

I tried:

```
UPDATE myusers SET canadd='{$tq}' WHERE IP='{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}' limit 1
```

but that didn't work. So I tried a few other things but those also didn't work.

Comment: [**Don't use `mysql_***` functions in new code**](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: `UPDATE` doesn't have the ability to create new rows.  It seems like there's something else going on here.

Comment: yeah,I also add stuff so:
mysql_query("INSERT INTO myusers (username,password,IP,Game) VALUES ('{$_GET['un']}','{$_GET['pw']}','{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}','{$_GET['ge']}')");
and the default value is 0.It's for an online game sort of.(The user can add up to 4 accounts)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Inserting a new row if there are less than three rows with that IP address?